# How can we read from Google Sheets into a DF in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am running this code (exactly the same).

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


# use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Find a workbook by name and open the first sheet
# Make sure you use the right name here.
sheet = client.open("Sheet1").sheet1

# Extract and print all of the values
list_of_hashes = sheet.get_all_records()
print(list_of_hashes)
```

I am not totally sure if this line is correct:

```
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
```

Anyway, I followed the instructions from this link.

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html

I clicked 'My Projectt' > 'Service Account' > 'Enable'.  I downloaded the JSON file, named it 'client_secret.json' and put it in this directory: 'C:\Users\ryans\client_secret.json'.  Finally, I open the json file, got the 'client_email inside client_secret.json' and put it in 'Share' and hit the 'Save' button.  Now, when I run the script above, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-20-870ca6cceea6>", line 12, in <module>
    sheet = client.open("Sheet1").sheet1

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 123, in open
    self.list_spreadsheet_files()

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 96, in list_spreadsheet_files
    res = self.request('get', url, params=params).json()

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 79, in request
    raise APIError(response)

APIError: {'errors': [{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions', 'message': 'Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.'}], 'code': 403, 'message': 'Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.'}
```

I'm not sure what is wrong here.  Could it be a permissions issue?

### Update

I added this line:

```
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']
```

[image]

[image]

My Google Sheet looks like this:

[image]

Now, I am changing the code to this:

```
import os
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# make sure the 'client_secret.json' is getting picked up...
os.getcwd()

# use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
scope = ['https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PBB1eJ7zbcLyj7vsdrB8nEyZ9Ri0Nds8M2yFB0zEN1Q/edit#gid=0']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Find a workbook by name and open the first sheet
# Make sure you use the right name here.
sheet = client.open("Sheet1").sheet1

# Extract and print all of the values
list_of_hashes = sheet.get_all_records()
print(list_of_hashes)
```

When I try to run that script, I get this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-34-e695bcd89439>", line 10, in <module>
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gspread\__init__.py", line 38, in authorize
    client.login()

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 51, in login
    self.auth.refresh(http)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 545, in refresh
    self._refresh(http)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 749, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 819, in _do_refresh_request
    raise HttpAccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg, status=resp.status)

HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_scope: Invalid oauth scope or ID token audience provided.
```

Both my 'Google Drive API' and 'Google Sheets API' are enabled.  I followed the 7 steps listed in the link below.

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html

Finally, I clicked 'Share' on the Google Sheets page.  Still, I'm getting this weird error, as described above.

Note: here is an image of my Google Sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Issue and solution:

When I saw the script of gspread, it seems that when `open("Sheet1")` is run, the files.list method of Drive API is used. [Ref](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/gspread/client.py#L81) In your script, only `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds` is used for the scopes. I think that by this, the error of `insufficientPermissions` occurs. In order to avoid this, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

From:

```
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
```

To:

```
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']
```

- `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds` is for Sheets API v3. The Sheets v3 API is shut down on September 30, 2020. So in this case, I recommend to use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` as the scope for using Sheets API. Also, gspread uses Sheets API v4.

#### Note:

- If you want to use the methods for modifying the file metadata, please use the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` instead of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`.

#### References:

- [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread)
- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Authorizing requests of Migrate to the Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration#authorizing_requests)

Comment: Hey there Tanaike.  I just updated my original post, from 'Update:' down.  Do you have any additional ideas as to how I can get this working?  Thanks.

Comment: @ASH Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When I saw your updated question, the scope uses `scope = ['https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PBB1eJ7zbcLyj7vsdrB8nEyZ9Ri0Nds8M2yFB0zEN1Q/edit#gid=0']`. This value is not the correct scope. So how about modifying to `scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']`?

Comment: I just tried your suggestion.  Now, I am getting this:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-49-43d739a87041>", line 16, in <module>
    sheet = client.open('Sheet1').sheet1

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 131, in open
    raise SpreadsheetNotFound

SpreadsheetNotFound

Comment: @ASH Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I could confirm that the issue of the scope and authorization were resolved. About the new error message, it means that the Spreadsheet name of `Sheet1` is not found. So I think that you might misunderstand `Sheet1` of `sheet = client.open("Sheet1").sheet1`. But, unfortunately, I'm not sure about the **Spreadsheet title**, which is the Spreadsheet filename, you want to use. So please confirm the Spreadsheet title again and set `###` of `sheet = client.open("###").sheet1`.

Comment: @ASH You can see the document about this at https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#opening-a-spreadsheet

Comment: I just added one more image to illustrate my setup (in my original post).  I think the Python code is pointing to the wrong object, or for some reason it's looking at the wrong object.  The sheet is named 'Sheet1' and in the code, I am telling it to open 'Sheet1', but it's not doing that.  Maybe I need to start over, from the beginning......

Comment: @ASH Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. From your added image, "Sheet1" is the sheet name in the Spreadsheet. In your case, the Spreadsheet title is `ryan-test@###`. So please set like `sheet = client.open("ryan-test@###").sheet1`. Please correctly input `###` from your Spreadsheet title. But from your image, I think that you are using the email of service account as the Spreadsheet title. So I worry if the Spreadsheet is shared with the email of service account. Please also check this.

Comment: I made the changes you stated; still getting the same error: 'SpreadsheetNotFound'.  Very weird.  I'll try it again tomorrow morning.  Getting late here now.  Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @ASH Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I think that from your replying, the issues of scopes and authorization of the modified script could be resolved. So I think that your initial question was resolved. As your new issue, the Spreadsheet title is required to be used when you want to use `open("###")`. But unfortunately, I think that your doesn't put the correct value for the Spreadsheet title. By this, such error occurs. So for example, how about renaming the Spreadsheet title to "Sheet1"? By this, `sheet = client.open("Sheet1").sheet1` can be used. How about this?

Comment: @ASH I noticed your this thread https://stackoverflow.com/q/60618445/7108653 I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: It's definitely NOT your fault.  Something is still off with me setup.  When I figure out what the issue is, I'll post my final results.  I am working on some other things in the meantime, so it's taking longer than I thought to get this thing up and running.

Comment: @ASH Thank you for replying. I think that when the flow of your setting is detail checked, your issue can be resolved. So I would like to wait for your additional information of your current situation.

Comment: Ok, I finally figured it out!!  In the file named 'statup_funding.json', you have to grab the email that is generated, then click the 'Share' button on the Spreadsheet, and paste THAT EMAIL ADDRESS into the window that opens.  Then, everything works as expected.  Here is a final version of my now-working code.

Comment: Your solution definitely helped me get going in the right direction!  I just up-voted your original post!!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author to move it from the question post)*.

I finally figured out how this works.  In the file named 'statup_funding.json', you have to grab the email that is generated, then click the 'Share' button on the Spreadsheet, and paste THAT EMAIL ADDRESS into the window that opens. Then, everything works as expected.

Here is the final version of my now-working code.

```
import gspread
#Service client credential from oauth2client
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
# Print nicely
import pprint
#Create scope
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
#create some credential using that scope and content of startup_funding.json
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('startup_funding.json',scope)
#create gspread authorize using that credential
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
#Now will can access our google sheets we call client.open on StartupName
sheet = client.open('Test_Sheet').sheet1
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
results = sheet.get_all_records()
results
```